# Diffucult Differential equation, Please help

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-derivative

I am try to solve the following Problem

the nonhomogeneous term contains modified bessel function K1

please give me advice

$$\lambda^2 Y- Y''= \frac{\lambda^3 (G)     K[1,\lambda(G^2+y^2)^{1/2})]}{(G^2+y^2)^{1/2}}$$

I tried

`DSolve [\[Lambda]^2 f[y] - f''[y] == (\[Lambda]^3 G BesselK[1, \[Lambda] Sqrt[y^2 + G^2]])/Sqrt[y^2 + G^2], f[y], y]`

Comment: Couple of questions: 
(1) Is your question about solving the problem in Mathematica/a computer driven approach?
(2) Did your expression get a result from the computer? If so what was it?
(3) I take it $Y$ is a function of $y$ and $\lambda$ and $G$ are constants?

Comment: The homogeneous terms would be $Y(y)=C_1 e^{\lambda y}+C_2 e^{-\lambda y}.$ Not at all sure what sort of ansatz you'd want for the non-homogeneous bit. That is the trick, isn't it?

Comment: yes i hope to get the particular solution according to the non-homogeneous term

Comment: I know the homogeneous solution for this differential equation is Y=yh+yp  , and yp solution give the solution depend on some sort of integral, the problem here now  that I don't know how the two integrals can be solved and give something so simple in the end, there's something i'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

Try variation of parameters.

But first replace the 1-variable 2nd-order equation with 2-variable 1st-order equations (I assume you're familiar with matrix notation) :

$$\begin{bmatrix} Y' \\ V' \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} V \\ \lambda^2Y-\lambda^3G\,K_1\Big(\lambda\sqrt{G^2+y^2}\Big)/\sqrt{G^2+y^2} \end{bmatrix}.$$

From Adrian's comment, the homogeneous part of this,

$$\begin{bmatrix} Y' \\ V' \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} V \\ \lambda^2Y \end{bmatrix},$$

has solutions

$$\begin{bmatrix} Y \\ V \end{bmatrix} = c_1\begin{bmatrix} e^{\lambda y} \\ \lambda e^{\lambda y} \end{bmatrix} + c_2\begin{bmatrix} e^{-\lambda y} \\ -\lambda e^{-\lambda y} \end{bmatrix}.$$

Now replace $c_1$ and $c_2$ with variables $u_1$ and $u_2$, and the original equation reduces to

$$u_1'\begin{bmatrix} e^{\lambda y} \\ \lambda e^{\lambda y} \end{bmatrix} + u_2'\begin{bmatrix} e^{-\lambda y} \\ -\lambda e^{-\lambda y} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ -\lambda^3G\,K_1\Big(\lambda\sqrt{G^2+y^2}\Big)/\sqrt{G^2+y^2} \end{bmatrix},$$

which gives

$$u_1'e^{\lambda y}=-u_2'e^{-\lambda y}=-\lambda^2G\frac{K_1\Big(\lambda\sqrt{G^2+y^2}\Big)}{2\sqrt{G^2+y^2}}.$$

I don't know if this helps; I don't have much experience with Bessel functions.